# How to retrieve data child of child from firebase / Android

Tags: java, android

[Here is my firebase database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okuuI.jpg)

[Here is the info.class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r07iz.jpg)

[Here is the insert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXPwG.jpg)

I want to get all the data from firebase to  List View

How can i get all data under "information" data list ?
please help

```
db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
ref = db.getReference("infomation");

  protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            infoList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot infoSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                 info info = infoSnapshot.getValue(info.class);
                 infoList.add(info);

            }
            InfoList adapter = new InfoList(Welcome.this, infoList);
            listViewInfo.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: can u put info.class here. you need to add name attribute , getter and setter in there

Comment: i already put the info class there, can help me to solve the problem ?

Comment: Your info.class is ok. You need to change data adding part. Then this will work. can you put data insertion part ?

Comment: @Lucefer i already put the insert in there please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your insertion part, you need to change it like below,

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("information");
ref.child( FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(in);
```

but if you want to save data like save the data like

> information >uid> random value > then the data

that use change data retrieving part like below

```
 for (DataSnapshot infoSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren().getChildren()){

                 info info = infoSnapshot.getValue(info.class);
                 infoList.add(info);

}
```

Comment: but i want save the data like > information >uid> random value > then the data.

Comment: can explain the code for me, i am new. and thank for the answer

Comment: @偉傑張 try it now.

Comment: @偉傑張 concept behind this is u need to first get that random number using dataSnapshot.getChildren() after that u need to get children values of that datasnapshots